# Can't install shadowfox on mozilla firefox, need help!

Tags: software-installation, firefox, mozilla

I' am new to the Ubuntu OS from Windows and I googled how to give a file permission to execute but it does not run after double-clicking it.

Is there a way to run it from the terminal or whatever I should do?

Comment: Are you talking about: https://github.com/overdodactyl/ShadowFox ?

Comment: yes the linux file won't execute for me. it tells me it could not display shadowfox if i try to run it as is or if i give it permission, nothing happens when i run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. Download

Download the linux file

- 32 bit: https://github.com/SrKomodo/shadowfox-updater/releases/download/v1.7.10/shadowfox_linux_x32
- 64 bit: https://github.com/SrKomodo/shadowfox-updater/releases/download/v1.7.10/shadowfox_linux_x64

[Download section](https://overdodactyl.github.io/ShadowFox/#)

## 2. Make it executable

Open a terminal and navigate to the download dir:

for example:

`cd ~/Downloads`

then make the downloaded file executable via

`chmod +x shadowfox_linux_x64`

## 3. Install

There are CLI or GUI install instructions [here](https://github.com/SrKomodo/shadowfox-updater/blob/master/README.md). I've tested the cli method on 16.04 (64bit) which works without issues.

Back in the terminal execute the installer/updater via:

`./shadowfox_linux_x64`

which opens a CLI installer dialog where you select the profile and select the install option.

Have fun.

Comment: When I entered the command line, nothing seemed to happen. I don't know why shadowfox isn't  cooperating. https://imgur.com/a/ImdnVLz

Comment: @QuanDo From your comment: make the directory where the file is located the working directory: `cd Desktop` and then run the file with `./shadowfox_linux_x64`.

Comment: @QuanDo i've updated the instructions. should be easier to understand & follow now. Good luck. If the issue is solved then, please consider marking the thread as solved.